# MATLAB - Condition to do something only once every x number of loops

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, logic, logical-operators

I am trying to change the value of `z` by **+1** every **750th, 1500th, 2250th,...,etc** loop and this is what I have written:

```
len = 1500000;
y = 750;
z = 1;
for i = 1:len
    if (i == [y.*(1:2000)])
        z = z + 1;
    end
end
```

Why is the value of `z` not changing? Can someone tell me what's wrong with my `if` statement please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB only considers an array to be `true` *if* all elements are `true`. So with that in mind, if we look at your conditional for your `if` statement

```
i == (y .* (1:2000))
```

What this returns is an array of 2000 values where they are either all `false` (in the case where `i` isn't a multiple of `y`) and all `false` except for one `true` value when it is. Even when there is one `true`, this still evaluates to `false` and your `if` statement will never be evaluated.

A better way to do this is to use [`mod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) to check if a given `i` is a multiple of `y`

```
if mod(i, y) == 0
    z = z + 1;
end
```

However, if the only contents of your loop are what you have shown, then you can simply omit the iterations that you don't care about

```
for i = y:y:len
    z = z + 1;
end
```

If you actually do want to compare the array as you showed though, you'd be best to compute `y .* 1:2000` outside of the loop and then use `ismember` to see if `i` is in the array

```
tmp = y .* (1:2000);

for i = 1:len
    if ismember(i, tmp)
        z = z + 1;  
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense now.